# Ignoring blanks in IFF condition in SSRS expressions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

iif(Fields!ABC.Value<=Fields!XYZ.Value and Fields!XYZ.Value<=Fields!PQR ,"Y","N")

Here ABC,XYZ and PQR are date fields.

The problem is if any ABC/XYZ/PQR  is empty then it always returns N but i want if any of these are blank then the condition ignores the blank and check the next condition

eg. if ABC is blank then Fields!ABC.Value<=Fields!XYZ.Value is ignored and the condition after and is checked and return the value according to that.

Please suggest any solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if XYZ is blank?

Comment: Thanks BhupeshC ...Then it should skip both conditions and return Y. I have written part of query here.. in actuall query i have 11 such dates  and i want to check whether these dates are in increasing order or consecutive dates can be same. And few of them are blak as well. So i am able to check sequence but when any date is blank in all 11 dates then it always return N. I want to skip any blanks in the condition. I hope i am able to explain my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: by blank do you mean null or just space?

Comment: Blanks are NULL in the data, only NULL. Date fields does not have spaces at all. So we donot have to check for spaces.

Answer (score 1):

since you are checking for the condition only when another condition is true, you will need nested `iif`. Again since you want to skip the condition if any of the dates are null, you would need to check for each date before you put them into `iif` block.

You can try something like this

```
=iif(
iif(isnothing(Fields!ABC.Value) or isnothing(Fields!XYZ.Value),true,Fields!ABC.Value<=Fields!XYZ.Value) and 
iif(isnothing(Fields!XYZ.Value) or isnothing(Fields!PQR .Value),true,Fields!XYZ.Value<=Fields!PQR.Value) ,"Y","N")
```

Comment: Now here the problem is ... when XYZ is blank then the expression will show true which is not correct. because we have not compared ABC and PQR. Any suggestion?

Comment: You said in your previous comment that if XYZ is blank, then it should return Y

Comment: See here is my problem.. i Have 11 dates which should be in a sequence starting from 1 to 11. Any of these can be blank as well. And if the dates are blank then i do not have to consider that date. Like that i have to check if all these are in sequence. This is required in one shipment racking solution i am working on.

Comment: does it mean, that if there is any blank date in any of the conditions, that condition is ignored and the next condition is evaluated? If that is what is required, then there will be 2 conditions skipped when a blank date is encountered. Again, is it true, that in case if there is a blank date, then it doesnt become a part of the check at all?

Comment: Yes.. eg.  D1<=D2<=D3<=D4<=D5<=D6....  Now if D2 is blank then it should compare D1 with D3 . or if D5 id blank then it should compare D4 with D6.